# How do I reorganize my dataframe to run Krippendorff's alpha?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to reorganize my dataframe so that I can run Krippendorff's alpha. What function/rudimentary solution can I find?

Here's what my dataframe looks like:

[image]

That is, each participant has 7 rows (for 7 observations). Each observation was assessed by two different people. I'd like my dataframe to have three columns: Code, Transcriber1, Transcriber 2. Under "Transcriber1" would appear the error scores of the first transcriber, whatever the name is, and under "Transcriber2", the scores for the second. That is, I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Any thoughts? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks community!

Comment: Please do not use images to show input since it means that those answering must retype the data.  This time I have done it for you in my answer (but changed Error to sequence numbers to avoid typing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Assuming input `DF` is as in the Note at the end create a `Transcriber` column with values `Transcriber1` and `Transcriber2` and a `Seq` column with sequence numbers and finally use `spread` to convert to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Transcriber = as.numeric(factor(Transcriber, levels = unique(Transcriber)))) %>%
  group_by(Transcriber = paste0("Transcriber", Transcriber), add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Seq = seq_along(Errors)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  spread(Transcriber, Errors) %>%
  select(-Seq)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
    Code Transcriber1 Transcriber2
   <dbl>        <int>        <int>
 1  1011            1            8
 2  1011            2            9
 3  1011            3           10
 4  1011            4           11
 5  1011            5           12
 6  1011            6           13
 7  1011            7           14
 8  2011           15           22
 9  2011           16           23
10  2011           17           24
11  2011           18           25
12  2011           19           26
13  2011           20           27
14  2011           21           28
```

**2) Base R** A solution using only base R would be:

```
make_factor <- function(x) factor(x, levels = unique(x))
DF2 <- transform(DF, 
  Transcriber = paste0("Transcriber", ave(as.numeric(Transcriber), Code, FUN = make_factor)),
  Seq = ave(Errors, Code, Transcriber, FUN = seq_along))
r <- reshape(DF2, dir = "wide", idvar = c("Seq", "Code"), timevar = "Transcriber")[-2]
names(r) <- sub("Errors.", "", names(r))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
DF <- data.frame(Code = rep(c(1011, 2011), each = 14), 
  Transcriber = rep(c("Anna", "David", "Susan", "Anna"), each = 7),
  Errors = 1:28)
```